# Fastest way to crop an image without exceeding image dimensions in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, real-time

Using matlab.

Suppose I have:

- An image `i` with "MaxWidth" number of pixels in the horizontal direction and "MaxHeight" number of pixels in the vertical direction.
- A retangular ROI defined by the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right pixels as in

`ROI = [yleft , xleft ; yright , xright]`

I was wondering what would be the fastest way to compute `i_crop`, where `i_crop`is the image that contains only the pixels that were in `i` and inside the given ROI.

ROI's like `[-10 , -10 ; 1000 , 1000]` in an 400x400 image should be regarded as `[1 , 1 ; 400 , 400]`

---

I came up with both of this so far:

### crop1

```
ROI(ROI<1)=1;
ROI(ROI(:,1)>MaxHeight) = MaxHeight;
ROI(find(ROI(:,2)>MaxWidth)+2) = MaxWidth;
i_crop = i(ROI(1,1):ROI(2,1),ROI(1,2):ROI(2,2),:);
```

And

### crop2

```
ymin = ROI(1,1);
xmin = ROI(1,2);
ymax = ROI(2,1);
xmax = ROI(2,2);

if ymin < 1
  ymin = 1;
end
if xmin < 1
  xmin = 1;
end
if ymax < 1
  ymax = 1;
end
if xmax < 1
  xmax = 1;
end

if ymin > MaxHeight
  ymin = MaxHeight;
end
if ymax > MaxHeight
  ymax = MaxHeight;
end
if xmin > MaxWidth
  xmin = MaxWidth;
end
if xmax > MaxWidth
  xmax = MaxWidth;
end

i_crop = i(ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax,:);
```

The latter runs faster:

```
>> im = imread('peppers.png');
>> tic, for i =1:100000 i_c = crop1(im,[0 0 ; 60 60],512,384); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 2.053574 seconds.
>> tic, for i =1:100000 i_c = crop2(im,[0 0 ; 60 60],512,384); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 1.667059 seconds.
```

Hope I made myself clear, thank's in advance!

Comment: [-10 , -10 ; 1000 , 1000] is not clear. Can you give a proper example?

Comment: Suppose the image "i" is a 400x400 image. Then the ROI specified by `[-10, 1 ; 400 , 400]` would have the topleft pixel not in the image (since it would be at position -10,1)! For my purposes, when this happens, the topleft pixel should be considered at the 1,1 position. The same reasoning holds for the bottomright pixel (if its position is beyond the boundaries of the image).

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox? `imcrop` can take a crop rectangle as an argument and you can use `rectint` to find the intersection between the ROI and a rectangle for the whole image, i.e. [1 1 MaxWidth MaxHeight]. Don't know how fast it is though.

Comment: Well, you could certainly implement `crop2` with less code by using, e.g., `xmin = max(1, min(ROI(1, 2), MaxWidth))`, but I highly doubt you're going to ever get anything faster than simple matrix indexing as you are already using. Though if you are doing this in a loop and all the ROIs are the same size, preallocation of the output could save you some time.

Comment: Thank's so far. Why posting comments instead of answers?